# Qt 5 produce random attribute order in XML

Tags: xml, qt, random, qt4, qt5

When switching from Qt 4.8 to Qt 5.x you may notice that each time you save XML document it produce random attribute order inside the file.
It makes no problem for programaticaly reading the XML document because attributes are allowed to be stored in any order when XML is deserialized. It is a problem when you track changes of output XML files using GIT, SVN, etc. - it is not possible to tell if the data inside XML file changed or the attribute structure changed.

Is it possible to generate XML files in Qt 5.x the same way as in Qt 4.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to generate the same way as in Qt 4.8 which saved XML attributes the same order it read them.
But there is a way to get rid off the randomness and generate the XML files always with the same order which may or may not be the same order it read them. In other words repeated saved will produce same results.

Why Qt 5.x save attributes randomly? Because it uses QHash to store the attributes and QHash class has been modified to patch algorithmic complexity attacks which is described here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qhash.html#algorithmic-complexity-attacks

If you are using QHash to store some data in specific order then switching to Qt 5.x will break your code.

**The solution:**

1) Lock the hash seed using evironment variable:

```
void main( void )
{
    qputenv("QT_HASH_SEED", "0");
    ...
}
```

It will lock the hash seed to one value between processes and will produce the same XML output everytime.

**Iv noticed that eveything is fine until I run the program on the other machine - then the output is again different but the same everytime I save the XML.**

2) Lock the hash seed using global variable

```
extern Q_CORE_EXPORT QBasicAtomicInt qt_qhash_seed;
void main( void )
{
    qt_qhash_seed.store(0);
    ...
}
```

This time Iv got the same output between processes and between computers which is more or less the same way as saved using Qt 4.8.

Comment: What are the security implications of this considering that hashes might be used for other things in a program than some XML order?

Answer (score 8):

I tried play with the hash seed, but it works fine only if you use one machine. If a file created on first machine open on second the same code doesn't produce the same order even if i set the hash seed to the same value. So, i just decided to find another solution.

I decided to use [QXmlStreamWriter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html) class as a wrapper. Each time i save QDomDocument i parse it and write through QXmlStreamWriter. This helps me convert an xml DOM to [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML).

Here is code i used. Maybe someone will find it useful.

```
bool MyDomDocument::SaveCanonicalXML(QIODevice *file, int indent, QString &error) const
{
  QXmlStreamWriter stream(file);
  stream.setAutoFormatting(true);
  stream.setAutoFormattingIndent(indent);
  stream.writeStartDocument();

  QDomNode root = documentElement();
  while (not root.isNull())
  {
    SaveNodeCanonically(stream, root);
    if (stream.hasError())
    {
        break;
    }
    root = root.nextSibling();
  }

  stream.writeEndDocument();

  if (stream.hasError())
  {
    error = tr("Fail to write Canonical XML.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void SaveNodeCanonically(QXmlStreamWriter &stream, const QDomNode &domNode)
{
  if (stream.hasError())
  {
    return;
  }

  if (domNode.isElement())
  {
    const QDomElement domElement = domNode.toElement();
    if (not domElement.isNull())
    {
        stream.writeStartElement(domElement.tagName());

        if (domElement.hasAttributes())
        {
            QMap<QString, QString> attributes;
            const QDomNamedNodeMap attributeMap = domElement.attributes();
            for (int i = 0; i < attributeMap.count(); ++i)
            {
                const QDomNode attribute = attributeMap.item(i);
                attributes.insert(attribute.nodeName(), attribute.nodeValue());
            }

            QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator i = attributes.constBegin();
            while (i != attributes.constEnd())
            {
                stream.writeAttribute(i.key(), i.value());
                ++i;
            }
        }

        if (domElement.hasChildNodes())
        {
            QDomNode elementChild = domElement.firstChild();
            while (not elementChild.isNull())
            {
                SaveNodeCanonically(stream, elementChild);
                elementChild = elementChild.nextSibling();
            }
        }

        stream.writeEndElement();
    }
  }
  else if (domNode.isComment())
  {
    stream.writeComment(domNode.nodeValue());
  }
  else if (domNode.isText())
  {
    stream.writeCharacters(domNode.nodeValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: You can lock the hash seed using global variable - check my answer

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i already did this and it doesn't work pretty stable. Yes, you get the same result on the same machine, but result is different if move to another machine. My approach is more predictable.

Comment: I don't agree - it is working in our production software between machines

Comment: Good. But i am talking about a case where you create a file on first machine. Then move the file to another, open it and resave. In this case result will be different. Each next save on the second machine produce the same order. The order unique for the second machine. But first saving on the second machine change the order. This is the reason why i proposed this solution. If your approach works for you and other i don't mind.

Comment: I used this way instead of the accepted answer for the same reason in the #dismine comment above.

Comment: This answer more right cause of locking QT_HASH_SEED not work on different machines. Much thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In more recent versions of Qt you can override the hash seed as follows:

```
#include <QHash>
int main() {
    qSetGlobalQHashSeed( 0 );
}
```